# TransformIgnore all react-native node modules for jest?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, babel-jest

I have this long list of react native node modules to ignore. I know that I need to ignore all of them. Is there a way I can refactor the following `transformIgnorePatterns` array into something cleaner?

```
"transformIgnorePatterns": ["node_modules/(?!(react-native|react-native-linear-gradient|react-native-svg|react-native-config|react-native-version-number|react-native-permissions|react-native-iphone-x-helper|react-navigation|react-native-htmlview|react-native-tag-input|react-native-fade-in-image|react-native-calendars|react-native-scrollable-tab-view|react-native-store-review)/)"],
```

I have tried the below but it simply didn't work.

`"transformIgnorePatterns": ["node_modules/react-(?!(native|native-*))]"`

Thank you

Comment: have you tried `["node_modules/.*/react-native"]`? what does it mean "did not work"? may you have nested `node_modules` folders in your project?

Comment: Hey! This ended up working. Just a little bit of REGEX. ```"transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(react-native|react-native.+)/)"
    ],```